# What is the Android Studio Terminal Pane?

Tags: android, android-studio

This may seem trivial, but I really can`t find anything with Google, so I ask here: What is the "Android Studio Terminal pane" mentioned here (under "Add the configuration file to your project"),
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client
and where can I find it?

Comment: link doesn't open

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here it is! Bottom of your Android Studio, select Terminal.
[image]

You can also go to: Tools -> Open Terminal

**Hint for Android Studio**: Menu Help -> Find Action -> type what are you looking for. Android Studio will give you couple matches accordingly to your search criteria. Most of the times you can find what you are looking for with this "Find Action" option.

Comment: Is it posssible to save the terminal output in text file, I could not get complete output if I am trying to select all and copy method.

Answer (score 18):

The Android Studio Terminal Pane is the command prompt for Android devices and can be accessed through the following steps:

- Navigate to the top toolbar and click View
- Cick on Tools Window and select Terminal

[image: Access Terminal]

Alternativiely you can just press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

This is the shortcut for the Terminal.

The function of the Terminal is to help you run commands on you Virtual device directly from the Terminal.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: "The Android Studio Terminal Pane is the command prompt for Android devices" - it provided access to the system's terminal window and can do here anything you can do from your system's prompt, it's not limited to Android devices management.

Comment: Can you launch this terminal standalone(without Android studio)?

Comment: You can use the adb tools to run the terminal without Android Studio. [Here](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-201-10-basic-terminal-commands-you-should-know) is a list of basic commands.

Comment: Actually this shortcut can be used for all programs developed by JetBrains.

Comment: This feature is a redundant/uselesss thing. The environment isn't even readily configured for Android SDK.

Answer (score 9):

**Android Terminal** - this is command line.

No difference actually between using **Android Terminal** or using command line.

This is just a handy tool inside IDE.

You can find it in `View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal` **or** tap double <kbd>Shift</kbd> and type `Terminal`

> Tip : in any cases you can use double <kbd>Shift</kbd> for find everything in Intellij Idea

Comment: are terminal and console same in Android Studio  ?

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio Panel is like Normal terminal, but there is the difference between them.  Normal Terminal point home directory  of operating system and Android Studio terminal point the directory of Project.

Comment: So, the android terminal can also run adb shell just like command prompt , right?

Answer (score 3):

If you are on **Windows or Linux** Just press **ALT + F12** then it will bring up the terminal.