# How can I force push to remote repository in GitHub in Android Studio 3.3.1?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I use Github for my project in Android Studio 3.3.1
I use the following code to return to a point both local repository and remote repository.

The line 1 can be launched in Android Studio 3.3.1 IDE.

1. Can the line 2  be launched in Android Studio 3.3.1 IDE ? If so, how can I do?
2. And more,  does it mean the content of  will overwrite the content of remote  without merger when I use *force* parameter to push ?

**Code**

```
git reset --hard <commit_hash>
git push origin <branch_name> --force
```

To Geno Chen: Thanks!

But Force Push is disabled, you can see the following image. I use Android Studio 3.3.1 in Windows 10 OS.

**Image**
[image]

Comment: Do you want to have 'click' option for this actions or can you just use built-in console?

Comment: Thanks! I hope to have a  'click' or just like 'check box' option  for force push.

Comment: Here is solution if you have closed terminal/console https://stackoverflow.com/a/32245083/10921202 and then you can type your desired actions

Comment: As I found in internet in Android Studio force push is disabled by default. Could you check VCS/Git/Push in options? Right now I don't have acces to my Android Studio.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps9Bd.jpg there is foto with this option in background

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Yes, you can. Just use the small drop-down menu in "Push Commits" window, elevated from `VCS` -> `Git` -> `Push...` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

[image: a "&Force Push" button in the drop-down menu]

2. Yes, use `--force` with `git push` will overwrite the remote repository with local, without a merger, [and can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---force). You may need to do a `git pull` first, or [use a "safer" `--force-with-lease`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---no-force-with-lease).

**Update**:

3. `Protected branches`, listed in `File` -> `Settings` -> `Version Control` -> `Git`, is not allowed to do a force push. So you have to choose another branch rather than `master` to do a force push, or remove settings of protected branches.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: is it possible to configure Android Studio so it enable the `--force-with-lease` instead of `--force` @geno-chen?

Comment: Intellijs uses `--force-with-lease` first, if it fails it shows you warning and switches to `--force`